# Ghost post filter by tag name

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I'm trying to create a `sidebar` for my Ghost blog with the tag name and a list of posts with that tag.

I have tried everything and can't get it to work. Here's the closest I have gotten:

**.hbs**

```
{{#foreach tags}}
    <h2>{{tag}}</h2>

    {{#foreach posts filter="tags:{{slug}}"}}
       <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
    {{/foreach}}

{{/foreach}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`#get`](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/helpers/get/) helper should solve this. Note that I've used `primary_tag` which stops duplicate posts from happening. If you don't mind that you can change `primary_tag` to `tag`:

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all"}}
    {{#foreach tags}}
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        {{#get "posts" limit="all" filter="primary_tag:{{slug}}"}}
            {{#foreach posts}}
                <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
            {{/foreach}}
        {{/get}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Hope this helps!